# NetBeans does not download?

Tags: java, netbeans

NetBeans does not download and shows me the message shown in the image below, knowing that I installed the jdk 13 and included in the environment variables correctly

[image: img]

Comment: Please provide any relevant error message in the post itself; not as a screenshot of the error message.

Comment: Which version of Netbeans are you trying to install?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the icon in the top left corner of your screenshot, it looks like you are trying to install NetBeans version 8.x using JDK 13. That is an invalid combination since NetBeans 8.x only supports the use of Java 7 or Java 8.

From the [NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 Installation Instructions](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/80/install.html):

> The Java SE Development Kit **(JDK) 7 Update 10 (or later) or JDK 8** is
>   required to install NetBeans IDE.

So unfortunately that error message is more than misleading; it is incorrect. Using releases newer than JDK 8 simply won't work.

To fix the problem you should install the latest release of JDK 8 before repeating your installation of NetBeans.

Alternatively, you could [download and install the latest version of NetBeans](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb111/nb111.html), Apache NetBeans 11.1. That approach is definitely preferable if it is feasible for you it  since it offers three advantages:

- You are using the latest version of NetBeans.
- You are using the most recent JDK.
- Since you have already installed JDK 13 you won't need to download any other JDK. Apache NetBeans 11.1 will run fine using JDK 13.